# Div fixed on vertical scroll but absolute on horizontal

Tags: html, css, css-position

here's what I want. I want a top bar AND navigation menu attached to the bar. I've done this no problem. I want to bar and the navigation menu to follow me if I scroll up and down.I can do this with a position fixed. but, if i have a fixed position, then when i scroll left to right, they follow.

I want to have both the top bar and the navigation menu follow as the user scrolls up and down but if they scroll left to right i want it to act like an absolute position, and become partially or completely hidden (depending on how much the user scrolls).

Is this possible? I've seen a couple of topics but haven't been able to get it to work for me.

Here is my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kyleseitz/rX4Vh/11/

I want EVERYTHING to move down with me when I scroll down and back up when I scroll up. But, if i get a horizontal scroll bar, I want to pass the viewing window over it.

I found the javascript on a previous question but i can't get it to work for me.

```
.slim {position: absolute;}


<div id="phantombar" class="slim">

<!--I Technically don't need these if they are not neccessary-->    
<div id="phantombar" class="fixed_elem">
<div id="headWrap">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollToFixed is a jQuery plugin that used to fix elements on the page (top, bottom, anywhere); however, it still allows the element to continue to move left or right with the horizontal scroll.

Website: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Demo: http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/

Answer (score 0):

try to use this. Maybe works :

```
$(function(){
   var elements = $('#ptm, #spt, #support, #act, #left_nav');
   elements.css('position', 'absolute');

   $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(this).scrollLeft()){
           elements.removeAttr('style').css('position', 'absolute');
       }else{
           elements.removeAttr('style').css('position', 'fixed');
       }
   });
});
```

`elements` can you add more, depending on needs.

Comment: It looks like it should, but there's no change in the way the divs scroll unfortunately :(. I've tried even removing the other two divs and just having phantombar and containing everything in that but i cant get it to work still.